# how to restrict private package access in gemfury so a specific user will only see a specific package in the package list?

Tags: gem-fury

I am using gemfury (https://gemfury.com/) and I want to give read access to a javascript private package to a specific user (a client).

Problem is, I don't want that user to be able to list all the packages in my organization.
The following command:

```
$ fury list
```

should only return the packages that the user has access to and not the complete list of my packages.

Thank you,

Brice